# Returning a pointer instance variable in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, return, command-pattern

I have a command pattern class with a pointer to another object (let's call it Duck). Its subclasses will use Duck, but to control and track when Duck is used (for debugging) I made Duck private and subclasses can only get it through a method getDuck();

```
class Command
{
    private:
        Duck* target;
    public:
        //Parametrized Constructor
        Command(Duck* _target);
        Duck* getDuck() { return target; }

        ...
};
```

I recently learned in *Effective C++* by Scott Myers the horrors of returning a pointer. I tried just returning the dereferenced version, but that caused a copy of target to be returned. Should I (and is there a way to) simply return a Duck object instead of a pointer to it?

Comment: Looks like what you want may be a [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, there are two kinds of pointers: owning and non-owning.

An owning pointer indicates that the holding object/function owns the allocation and is responsible for deleting the object.

A non-owning pointer is a "borrowed" object; the holding object/function does *not* own the object and is *not* responsible for cleaning it up.

Ideally, this manifests in the C++ type system since C++11 in the following ways:

- `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a unique-ownership pointer to a `T` object.  Exactly one object/function can own the allocation.
- `std::shared_ptr<T>` is a shared-ownership pointer to a `T` object.  Many objects/functions share ownership of the allocation, and the target object is deleted only when all of them are done with it.
- `T *` is a non-owning pointer.  This is returned by functions to indicate that the caller *does not* own the object.  The caller is *not* expected to delete the object; indeed, the caller *may not* delete it.  The caller is expected not to use the pointer once the owning object/function destroys the target object.

There is nothing inherently wrong with returning a raw pointer, though I would only return a pointer when the function needs to conditionally give access to an object it owns:

- `T *`: The function is returning a non-owning handle to an object, but it might not have an object so could return `nullptr`.  `T *` is "optional, non-owning object handle."
- `T &`: The function is returning a non-owning handle to an object, and it will always have such an object to return.  `T &` is "mandatory, non-owning object handle."

Note that not all standard library facilities will respect these guidelines; indeed not all of them can!  `new T` must return a `T *` because that's how it's defined to work.  These are guidelines that *you* should follow in *your* application.